# Install GCC 4.8 on Redhat 7 in offline mode

Tags: gcc, redhat

How to install GCC 4.8 on RHEL 7 in offline mode? (not registered with Redhat).
I searched for a solution but couldn't find a proper one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that we can use

1) Create a local yum repository from DVD/ISO file - Google search will throw lot of links. One such thing is https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1355683

2) Another option is use the Centos repository. Centos is derived from RHEL and should be safe. You can set this as you repository. But, I will go for the first one

Comment: Thanks and will try the 1st one

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about GCC 4.8, but V6.3.1 is available via the Developer Toolset.  See https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/updates/

I'm believe GCC 5.3 may still be accessible too.

There's a no-cost RHEL developer subscription to download here: https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download/

HTH